# Hyphen in "a much-needed physiological understanding of..."

Tags: hyphenation

Although it looks and feels perhaps superfluous to me, it seems the hyphen is correct in these sentences, according to Chicago or other style guides, but I wish to confirm this.

*A much-needed physiological understanding of habit and tradition in design relates them to neuromental economics.*

*Such study will be concerned with the much-needed “knowledge of the interacting morphogenetic agencies.”*

There's always [CMOS's hyphenation table](https://www.chicagomanualofstyle.org/book/ed17/part2/ch07/psec089.html) to consult, but I somewhat struggle with the description alongside the most similar example. Is the hyphen in the two above examples absolutely required?

Comment: By whom? This is pure opinion.

Comment: What by whom? Care to expand?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it should. Like the Chicago Manual of Style, AP also codified the [rules](https://www.prdaily.com/dashes-hyphens-ap-style/), and they aren't simple.  You should put a hyphen in a compound modifier like much-needed or accident-prone, except when:

- The term is common, as in "first class ticket."
- It's more than three words.
- It's an adverb containing very or a -ly word
- When describing dual heritage, like African American. (I wonder if this might be a recent political change. I've seen "African-American" often.)

I'll also add that if it's a common term that uses hyphens, such as I'd imagine you'd find in a dictionary, you keep the hyphens. Devil-may-care; happy-go-lucky; parent-child.

Comment: Superb answer. The guides address hyphenated compound modifiers before a noun, however, in this case we have them before a concept-as-noun (understanding) preceded by an adjective (physiological). Often these compound modifier hyphen questions are resolved by considering the phrase without the hyphen and seeing if it clearly changes meaning. That's _not_ the case with physiological understanding. And which word is the compound modifier targeting, physiological or understanding, and does the hyphen help answer that?  Do these factors have no bearing at all?

Comment: Glad you like the answer! If this is the answer you want, please click to accept the answer, on the left.

Comment: It can both be a superb answer and ywt not the answer sought. I've added a relevant follow-up, which you've seen before requesting a modification to my response.